# Database structure guidance

Tags: database, database-design

i have this object that i need to insert to database (include the right relation)
i try to find what is the best way to build the database tables with the right fields and relation..

my obects:

**objectA:**

```
String id;
String mode;
String name;
Dictionary dict<String code,List<Pair<String index,String val>>
```

**objectB:**

```
String sysId;
List<objectA> objectAs;
String seates;
```

it's should be one-to-many relation between objectB.sysId to objectA.id (many objectA to one objectB)
and in objectB the sysId is primary key.
now about objectA i don't know how to handle right the Dictionary...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE ObjectA
(
    Id     CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Mode   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Name   CHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ObjectA_Dict
(
    Id     CHAR(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES ObjectA,
    Code   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id, Code)
);

CREATE TABLE ObjectA_DictEntry
(
    Id     CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Code   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(Id, Code) REFERENCES ObjectA_Dict,
    Index  CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Value  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id, Code, Index)
);
```

Since you've not told us anything about the organization of the strings used to identify objects, it is hard to know how big to make them.  You can decide to use some sort of automatically allocated integer value in the tables if you wish; this would alter the way queries need to be written, but might play better with some of the tools that handle ORM (Object-Relational Mapping).  Since you've not identified which DBMS you're targeting, that too had to be left unillustrated.  In `ObjectA_DictEntry`, you could have `Id` as a foreign key referencing `ObjectA`, but that isn't necessary.  With the composite keys shown, you can work on just `ObjectA_DictEntry` without necessarily having to refer to the other tables.  If you use automatically allocated values, you would be forced to do joins sometimes.

```
CREATE TABLE ObjectB
(
    SysId   CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Seates  CHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ObjectB_List
(
    SysId   CHAR(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES ObjectB,
    Id      CHAR(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES ObjectA,
    PRIMARY KEY (SysId, Id)
);
```

This is what I think your `ObjectB` schema should look like.  I think you should have showed what you think it should look like; it would have improved your question.